# FileUtils: readLines and writeLines methods not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, import

I'm new to Android Studio, so I followed directions to a video and an error constantly comes up that the methods ReadLines and writeLines do not exist.
I tried importing methods but none of them worked.

I assume this implementation was the one responsible for those methods, and it is in the correct location (app file) based on the instructions, but there is no error messages around it.

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qP4U_4QvojQ&list=PLrT2tZ9JRrf6cHOlMkbmTMFt0RzpJiRGX&index=4

`implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'`

Here's the MainActivity.java code that uses the methods

```
package com.example.simpletodo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.FileUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList items;

    Button btnAdd;
    EditText etItem;
    RecyclerView rvItems;
    ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        etItem = findViewById(R.id.etItem);
        rvItems = findViewById(R.id.rvItems);

        loadItems();

        ItemsAdapter.OnLongClickListener onLongClickListener = new ItemsAdapter.OnLongClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemLongClicked(int position){
                //Delete the item from the model
                items.remove(position);
                //Notify the adapter
                itemsAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item is removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                saveItems();
            }
        };
        itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(items);
        rvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
        rvItems.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String todoItem = etItem.getText().toString();
                //Add item to the model
                items.add(todoItem);
                //Notify adapter that an item is inserted
                itemsAdapter.notifyItemInserted(items.size() - 1);
                etItem.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item was added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                saveItems();
            }
        });
    }

    private File getDatafile(){
        return new File(getFilesDir(), "data.txt");
    }

    //This function will load items by reading every line of the data file
    private void loadItems(){
        try {
            items = new ArrayList<>(FileUtils.readLines(getDatafile(), Charset.defaultCharset()));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error reading items", e);
            items = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    //This function saves items by writing them into the data file
    private void saveItems(){
        try {
            FileUtils.writeLines(getDatafile(), items);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("MainActivitiy", "Error writing items", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That's what youngest for trying to learn programming from a video instead of the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

*instead* of

```
import android.os.FileUtils;
```

According to the documentation, [android.os.FileUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUtils) does not have `readLines()`
or `writeLines()` methods.

Comment: It said it's already defined in a single line import, thanks for the response though

Comment: @yumij Not in the code you posted. You imported a different class.

Comment: @user207421 https://gyazo.com/28be7fd9f8613d63289663f0c65e9170

Comment: @yumij We don't need the video. Your code as posted here and this answer are not the same, and no amount of irrelevant links can possibly change that. If there's something wrong with the video, that's just more proof that you wasted your time watching it when you should have looked up the documentation. You can't spend your programming career looking at third-party and third-rate sources and then asking here why they don't work. Use the documentation. That's what it's for.